bash script - check number of input arguments based on one input argument value
I have to create a bash script for which i need to give input arguments based on action type: insert/update.
In case of insert the bash script will need 3 input arguments but in case of update are necessary 4 arguments. Action type insert/update is also gave as input parameter.
How i can check the bash input arguments based on action type and to show a usageFunction() for users? How can i check if action type is I/U and if is not added an incorrect value?
The parameters will be like:
<test_case_a><test_value_a> I - this is for action insert marked by I as input parameter
<test_case_a><test_value_a> U <date_test_value_a> - this is for action update marked by U as input parameter
I tried to do it like this but i do not have the correct result.
#!/usr/bin/bash

helpFunction_U() {
    echo "Param 1: test_case_a"
    echo "Param 2: test_value_a"
    echo "Param 3: action"  
    echo "Param 4: date_test_value_a"
    exit }

help_Function_I() {
    echo "Param 1: test_case_a"
    echo "Param 2: test_value_a"    
    echo "Param 3: action"
    exit }

if [ -z "$3" ]    
then if [ "$3" = 'U' ]
     then if [ -z "$1" ] && [ -z "$2" ] && [ -z "$4" ]
          then
              echo "Some or all of the arguments are empty";
              helpFunction_U ;
          fi
     elif [ "$3" = 'I' ]
     then  if [ -z "$1" ] && [ -z "$2" ]
           then
               echo "Some or all of the arguments are empty";
               helpFunction_I ;
           fi
     else echo "Action "$3" unknown";
     fi
else echo "Action is not defined!" ;
     helpFunction_U;
fi


Why not just compare $# to the number of required arguments based on the parameter?

&& should be ||. When you use &&, it will only be true if all the arguments are empty, not "some or all".

because for I (insert are needed 3) and for update U are needed 4. and yes, all should be populated since this values will represent input for an insert/update statement

So if [ "$3" = 'I' ] && [ $# -ne 3 ]

The first if should be if [ -n "$3" ]

I recommend you use case to handle the different action values.

Just use a simple case statement.  eg:
#!/usr/bin/bash

usage() {
    cat <<- EOF
        usage: $(basename $0) [-h] test_case_a test_value_a action [date_test_value_a]

        The 'action' may be one of I (insert) or U (update).  If action
        is U, the date_test_value_a is required.  If action is I,
        date_test_value_a must not be specified.
    EOF
}

die() { echo "$* (-h for usage)"; exit 1; } >&2
case $1 in
-h|--help|-?) usage; exit 0;;
esac

case $3 in
I) test $# = 3 || die "Insert requires exactly 3 arguments";;
U) test $# = 4 || die "Update requires exactly 4 arguments";;
'') die "No action given";;
*) die "Invalid action";;
esac

Note that all error messages need to go to stderr (hence the >&2 redirect on the die function).  Also, don't propagate usage spew.  Emit an error message that succinctly describes the problem, and only write a usage statement when specifically requested by the user.  Although it is an unfortunately common practice over the past few decades, it is lazy programming.  Writing good error messages is hard.  Just printing the entire usage statement and forcing the user to figure out exactly what is wrong is a lazy way of avoiding having to write good error messages.
Also note that the <<- style heredoc only works properly if you indent your script properly (eg, with hard tabs, not with spaces).
